# Flexslider 2 bottom space (responsive)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, flexslider

*I know this question has been asked before, but I've tried all the solutions I've seen (like .flexslider { margin: 0 } ), and I just can't figure it out.*

I use a flexslider on this homepage - responsive of course.
The problem is this white space bellow my images... does someone know how I can get rid of it ?

My site : http://jeanvilar.revenons-a-nos-moutons.com/

Gaël

Comment: Can you also include the relevant code in your question. Otherwise if your link is ever inactive, these question would become useless. Typically, try to include code fragments.

Comment: we would need some code to fiddle around please - but maybe one thing is that your p.flex-caption has a `margin: 1.5rem` bottom and a `top: -100px` attribute. try to replace this with `top: 0; margin-top: -100px;` cause i think flexslider calculates it's height BEFORE positioning the element -100 top

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DomlThe-Bread!
I don't have any margin anymore on my p.flexcaption
I just tested it with top:0,margin-top:-100px; and it does not solve the problem.

Here is my flexcaption styles :

`p.flex-caption {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height:100px;
  top:-100px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1rem;
}`